# Java Find word in a String

Tags: java, regex

I need to find a word in a HTML source code. Also I need to count occurrence. I am trying to use regular expression. But it says 0 match found.

I am using regular expression as I thought its the best way. In case of any better way, please let me know.

I need to find the occurrence of the word "hsw.ads" in HTML source code.

I have taken following steps.

```
int count = 0;
{
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*(hsw.ads).*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(SourceCode);
    while(m.find())count++;
}
```

But the count is 0;

Please let me know your solutions.

Thank you.
Help Seeker

Comment: Remove the wildcards from the beginning and end of the pattern and try again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try this.

```
private int getWordCount(String word,String source){
        int count = 0;
        {
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(word);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(source);
            while(m.find()) count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Pass the word (Not pattern) you want to search in a string.

Answer (score 6):

You are not matching any "expression", so probably a simple string search would be better. [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) has `StringUtils.countMatches(source, "yourword")`.

If you don't want to include commons-lang, you can write that manually. Simply use `source.indexOf("yourword", x)` multiple times, each time supplying a greater value of `x` (which is the offset), until it gets -1

Comment: Hi @Bozho. Thank you for replying. May I know the package to import for using StringUtils?

Comment: I added a link to commons-lang. you'd have to add the jar to you classpath. Then the FQN is org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils

Comment: Ok.. Thanks.. I already have included commons-lang in my package and other packages too. That is why Eclipse IDE is suggesting more than one opetion for that class so I asked you.

Answer (score 1):

To find a string in Java you can use String methods `indexOf` which tells you the index of the first character of the string you searched for. To find all of them and count them you can do this (there might be a faster way but this should work). I would recommend using StringUtils CountMatches method.

```
String temp = string; //Copy to save the string
int count = 0;
String a = "hsw.ads";
int i = 0;

while(temp.indexOf(a, i) != -1) {
    count++;
    i = temp.indexof(a, i) + a.length() + 1;
}
```

Comment: better use `indexOf(a, i)` where `i` is increased each time

Comment: `temp = string` seems unnecessary. Why not just reference `string` directly?

Comment: @Steve Kuo Originally I was using substring instead on index and I didn't want to screw up the string. but since I changed it, there is no reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

StringUtils.countMatches(SourceCode, "hsw.ads") ought to work, however sticking with the approach you have above (which is valid), I'd recommend a few things:
1. As John Haager mentioned, remove the opening/closing .* will help, becuase you're looking for that exact substring
2. You want to escape the '.' because you're searching for a literal '.' and not a wildcard
3. I would make this Pattern a constant and re-use it rather than re-creating it each time.

That said, I'd still suggest using the approaches above, but I thought I'd just point out your current approach isn't conceptually flawed; just a few implementation details missing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code and regular expression is valid.  You don't need to include the .* at the beginning and the end of your regex.  For example:

```
String t = "hsw.ads hsw.ads hsw.ads";
int count = 0;
Matcher m  = Pattern.compile("hsw\\.ads").matcher(t);
while (m.find()){ count++; }
```

In this case, count is 3.  And another thing, if you're going to use a regex, if you REALLY want to specifically look for a '.' period between hsw and ads, you need to escape it.